# Compare a time slot from sheet 1 between 2 time slots in Sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel, qt

I have 2 sheets of data with the following headers

SHEET 1:

```
NetID | TimeSlot | SlotName
```

SHEET 2:

```
NetID | StartTime| EndTime | SlotName
```

SO i need to do these things:

- IF TimeSlot (Sheet1) is IN BETWEEN StartTime & EndTime(sheet 2)  AND the NetID(sheet1) == NetID(sheet2) --> then Fill in the corresponding SlotTime(sheet2) INTO Sheet1's SlotName column.

Can anyone help me with this???
Please refer the photo i uploaded for better view of the data

[image: SAMPLE DATA I'm USING]

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Questions should only be posted after you have researched your issue and should include issue your attempts so far to solve it, a [Minimal, Complete, & Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a clear outline of the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure the time format you use is consistant across the two sheets. Do not use 9pm on one side and 09:00:00 on the other. Use the following format: HH:mm:ss.

Second, in your example one NetID in the first sheet does not have a match on the second sheet. (GHI <> IJK). I assumed this is an error. If not the formula below will return an error.

Finally, the answer:

```
=IF(AND(B1>=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),B1<=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0))),INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)))
```

and if you break it down to understand it looks like this:

```
=IF (
```

the condition to check that the time slot in the first sheet is between the relevant time range defined in the second sheet:

```
AND(
B1>=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),
B1<=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)))
```

Note: MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0) helps defining which range is relevant in the second sheet.
and with the same logic the output returns the name of the time slot:

```
INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

Comment: Hello Dan! thank you so much for this - looks great. I'm going to try it out.

Comment: Although - the NetID - is not in the SAME order in both sheets - I have to do a Vlookup(or something else) to get the value. Is ther any way i can obtain the SlotName in Sheet 1 if the NetIDs are not in the same order?

Comment: There is no need to do a vlookup here. the Match function will enable you to know in which row the time slot is. The Index function will then return it. It is the combination of these two functions that does what you are looking for.